# Hide popup automatically after a delay

Tags: google-chrome-extension

On clicking the extension icon, I want the popup to open for a few seconds and then disappear.

The default behavior is that the popup will disappear after clicking anywhere else on the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot prevent the popup from closing when the user clicks outside it.  You can, however, close the popup whenever you want.

Use `window.close()` in your `popup.html`

```
setTimeout(function () {
    window.close();
}, fewSeconds);
```

You will have to relax the [content security policy](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) if you want to place this function inline inside your popup.  You're better off putting it in an external file for your popup to fetch.